# Select min +1 mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de sacar el primer código libre que hay entre dos valores y no se que estoy haciendo mal que siempre me da `2` cuando hay números por encima de `2`.

este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
SELECT MIN(`Ean`)+1 as prox_ean_libre FROM `CodigosEan` WHERE `Ean` BETWEEN '843447200001' AND '843447299999' AND `empresa` = '199'
```

En la base de datos tengo un registro con el código 843447200003 pero me sigue dando `2` en vez de `4`.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara, pero, de lo que entiendo, aparentemente tienes un registro con `Ean = 843447200001`. Pero te diré que no veo nada en tu lógica que garantize que el valor devuelto esté libre.

Comment: si @sstan y otro con 843447200002 y otro con 843447200003, con lo que el siguiente ean libre tendría que ser 843447200004

Comment: Como te menciono mas arriba, el problema (en parte) es que no tienes ninguna lógica para determinar si el valor está libre. Simplemente pides el número mas pequeño y le agregas uno, lo que siempre será 2. No lo veo muy sorprendente. ¿Cual es el tipo de la columna `Ean`?

Comment: El campo Ean es bigint @sstan ¿como podría aplicar lógica para sacar ese valor?

Comment: Por lo que comentas en tu explicación, no querrás usar `MAX`, en lugar de `MIN`?. Al esperar valores superiores a 2, es lo que das a entender

Comment: no, porque puede haber codigos usados por encima. la idea es usar el primer codigo libre @JoseJavierSegura

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu consulta no inluye ninguna clase de lógica que se asegure que `MIN(Ean)+1` realmente resulte en un valor libre.

Una manera de corregir esto es por medio de agregar una expresión `NOT EXISTS` para filtrar a los resultados donde `Ean + 1` no apunte a un registro existente:

```
SELECT MIN(c.`Ean`)+1 as prox_ean_libre
FROM `CodigosEan` c
WHERE c.`Ean` BETWEEN 843447200001 AND 843447299999
AND c.`empresa` = '199'
and not exists (
  select null
    from `CodigosEan` c2
   where c2.`empresa` = c.`empresa`
     and c2.`Ean` = c.`Ean` + 1
)
```

Comment: me da null como resultado

Comment: El problema tiene que ver con la condición `c.empresa = '199'`. El problema es que no entiendo del todo como funcionan tus datos. Pero creo que es necesario agregar una condición más dentro del `NOT EXISTS` para considerar esa columna también. Edité mi respuesta.

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta correcta

Comment: Ahora si :) Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Te recomendaría primero que todo, convertir explícitamente tu código EAN a un tipo de datos numérico, ya que de todas formas estás haciendo una conversión implícita al usar

```
MIN(`Ean`)+1
```

Y esto seguramente te está generando problemas.

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(`Ean` AS BIGINT))+1 as prox_ean_libre 
FROM `CodigosEan` 
WHERE `Ean` BETWEEN '843447200001' AND '843447299999' 
AND `empresa` = '199';
```

Comment: Ean ya es un campo bigint, no se si sera importante. Al hacer esa consulta en phpmyadmin me da error #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'BIGINT))+1 as prox_ean_libre FROM `CodigosEan` WHERE `Ean` BETWEEN '843447200001' en la linea 1

Comment: si `EAN` ya es bigint, por qué estás entonces haciendo `BETWEEN` con strings?

Comment: ¿strings? ¿por usar '?

Comment: @Killpe claro, usar `'` es para identificar un string